# Вывести весь объект через alert

Tags: javascript

```js
let home = {
    Стены:4,
    Пол:1,
    Мебель: 25,
}

alert(home.Стены);
```

Выводит только одно свойство, как разом вывести все свойства данного объекта?

Comment: Данная строка `alert(home.Стены);` выводит не свойство, а значение свойства. Свойство - это пара ключ-значение. Вам нужно ключи, значения или всё вместе?

Comment: Да все вместе, есть ли такие методы в обьектах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
let home = {
  Стены: 4,
  Пол: 1,
  Мебель: 25,
}

alert(Object.entries(home).join('\n'));
```

Или так (см. [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)):

```js
let home = {
  Стены: 4,
  Пол: 1,
  Мебель: 25,
}

alert(JSON.stringify(home, null, 2));
```

Comment: Json это же отдельная библиотека типа Jquery?

Comment: Нет, это встроенный в JS объект с двумя методами, parse и stringify, для хранения и передачи значений в виде строк. Можно использовать и для читабельного вывода объектов и массивов в консоль или, как здесь, в alert.

Comment: Значит своих методов у объекта для данной задачи нет? Как я понимаю, чтобы решить задачу нужно объект перевести в new Map, как вы и сделали в первом варианте?

Comment: А join это же метод массива, разве его можно применить к new Map?

Comment: @Человек тут вообще нету `new Map`, `Object.entries` возвращает массив массивов, это не связано с `Map`. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: Object.entries преобразует объект в массив? Я все правильно понимаю?

Comment: У вас могла возникнуть ассоциация с Map, потому что `Object.entries` возвращает такой же массив массивов, какой можно использовать при создании Map, но Map мы тут не используем. И да, отдельного метода для удобного вывода объекта для чтения нет, поэтому можно использовать или JSON, или сначала превратить объект в массив массивов. Можно и просто `alert(Object.entries(home))`, но тогда все пары ключей и значений будут выведены в одну строку, будет не так читабельно.

Comment: Object.entries точно преобразует объект в массив? Чет я запутался((

Comment: Преобразует объект в массив массивов. В каждом подмассиве хранится пара из ключа и значения объекта.

Comment: Ну теперь все понятно =)